# Поведение setInterval для экземпляра класса

Tags: javascript, ооп, setinterval

На звание знатока JS не претендую.
При разработке учебного проекта сталкнулся с непонятной ситуацией.
Когда я запуска через `setInterval` метод экземпляра класса получаю сообщение

> "this.snakeBody is undefined"

Пример запуска `setInterval(snake.move, 500);`

А если обернуть вызов метода в функцию то всё работает (пример запуска

```
setInterval(function() {
  snake.move();
}, 500);
```

***Собственно говоря хочу понять, почему не работает вызов метода без обёртки.***

На всякий случай ссылка на песочницу: https://plnkr.co/edit/xnhafbsDVaZXp9D7CQLS

строка описания запуска - 146

Comment: типичная ошибка с потерей контекста, на это уже есть несколько вопросов с ответами

Comment: внутри  setintervel теряется контекст this.   тут можно или заменить функцию на стрелочную или делать как у тебя в примере. а так же  посмотри bind, call, apply - там подробно расписано

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, метода класса неправильно вызван:

`setInterval(snake.move(), 500)`

Но запись выше будет вызвана один раз при запуске `setInterval` при каждом нажатии кнопки. Поэтому смотрите ниже.

Во-вторых, `setInterval` в качестве первого аргумента должен получать функцию, которая запустит то, что Вам необходимо внутри себя с конкретным интервалом:

`setInterval(() => snake.move(), 500)`

Comment: Буду иметь ввиду, спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Удачи